# Spinner scrolling crashing application

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner which gets loaded through web-service call and it is working fine, but when I scroll it or select item second time it crashes the application. On first click it is working fine. I know it might be a problem with array length but could not  make it works out.

Here is my code:

```
Log.d("ArrayAdapter",""+ SpinnerData.length);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(abc.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SpinnerData);

spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
lv.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

SpinnerData is String array containing data coming from service.

The logcat looks like this:

```
02-15 10:40:40.350: W/System.err(992): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
02-15 10:40:40.360: W/System.err(992):  at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:329)
02-15 10:40:40.360: W/System.err(992):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject.getProperty(SoapObject.java:116)
02-15 10:40:40.360: W/System.err(992):  at ums.lovely.university.StudentPracMarsksDetails.soap(StudentPracMarsksDetails.java:216)
02-15 10:40:40.360: W/System.err(992):  at ums.lovely.university.StudentPracMarsksDetails$Search$1.run(StudentPracMarsksDetails.java:322)
02-15 10:40:40.360: W/System.err(992):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-15 10:40:40.360: W/System.err(992):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-15 10:40:40.360: W/System.err(992):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-15 10:40:40.370: W/System.err(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-15 10:40:40.370: W/System.err(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 10:40:40.370: W/System.err(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-15 10:40:40.370: W/System.err(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-15 10:40:40.370: W/System.err(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-15 10:40:40.370: W/System.err(992):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 10:40:40.370: D/The students3rfrfg4ry(992): ghsksrrsio
02-15 10:40:40.370: D/Else The studenty(992): ghskssio
02-15 10:40:41.130: D/AndroidRuntime(992): Shutting down VM
02-15 10:40:41.130: W/dalvikvm(992): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:329)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:325)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1284)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1570)
02-15 10:40:41.150: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
```

Comment: please post logs as text/code..

Comment: no it is not, I think I have added the "Select" at zero index of spinner that is causing error...

Answer (score 0):

How the function in onSelectedItemListener? 
Need to remember about the array length and the index of array. 
Array : 0 ... x 
and the length is x + 1


If still error, try to change android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem of arraryoutof index problem, I was assigning "Select" at index[0] of spinner, but this ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource() error is still there, i thin spinner is not getting the view